# Requiring a relevant job posting in order to message a job seeker

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Would it be possible to require that employers have a job posting (either public or private) attached to their message to job seekers?

I've recently been encountering a lot of recruiters who are contacting me just because of my C++ experience. After taking time out of my schedule to talk with these recruiters, I come to realize that the only skill I have relevant to the position they're filling is C++, or that the full job description is very unappealing to me.

In one case, I went through two interviews with a company, before realizing that I had no experience with the languages/stack they used, which immediately disqualified me. It wastes a lot of time for both the job seeker and employer when situations like this occur.

I'm not sure how others feel about this, but it would be nice to see a detailed description of the job attached to the initial contact from the employer. It would be much better than 'Oh hey, I see you do a lot of servery C++ development! We do a lot of that, too! Let's talk!' and then scheduling time for an interview, where you realize that the company only uses Java.

Comment: I think this is a good idea.  However, you really ought to find out what the position is before doing two interviews!

Comment: Well, the first interview was primarily theory and design. I asked about the technologies they use, and the person told me everything the company used, not specifically what I would be working with. In the second interview, I learned that the position I was applying for had nothing to do with anything I had experience with, aside from the design and theory.

Answer (score 7):

This would certainly be a useful feature.  Employers write large amounts about the position in the messages already, copying and pasting much of it in any given session.  Wrapping up the reusable parts in a job posting format would make it easier for the employer to share information about the position they are hiring for and the culture of the team (sort of like a resume).  It would also allow them to personalize the message more to the actual person they are sending it too and keep it significantly shorter (sort of like a cover letter).  The position is applying to you in candidate search after all.

Employers are not always hiring for a specific position, working with specific technologies.  This wouldn't work as well for the companies that are simply searching for talent, but those are certainly in the minority.